# Change button text based on radio button option using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I created an angular application that has a 2 radio controls and a text button.  I would like to change the text of the button under 2 separate conditions.
1. Changing the radio button will change it to either 'Upgrade' or 'Save'
2. When the text button is clicked the button is disabled and text changed to 'Processing'.

This is the html:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="outputType" value="Database">
    <label>Database</label>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="outputType" value="File">
    <label>Xml File</label>
</div>   
<div>
    <button id="upgradeDBButton" type="button" ng-click="UpgradeDatabase()" 
    ng-disabled="upgradeBtndisabled" class="btn btn-info" 
    style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;">{{upgradeBtnText}}</button>
</div>
```

This is the javascript

```
angular.module('vow-administration-ui')
  .controller('UpgradeCtrl', ['$scope',  '$modal', 'UpgradeDB', 'CreateXmlFile', 'TestConnection',
      function($scope, $modal, upgradeDB, createXmlFile, testConnection) { 

        $scope.title = 'Upgrade Database';
        $scope.upgradeBtnText = 'Upgrade Database';
        $scope.upgradeBtndisabled = false;
};      

$scope.UpgradeDatabase = function(){  
  var currentBtnText = $scope.upgradeBtnText;
  $scope.upgradeBtnText = 'Processing...';  
   $scope.upgradeBtndisabled = true;  
  upgradeDB.save({  ...
   }).$promise.then(function() {
     $scope.upgradeBtndisabled = false;  
      $scope.upgradeBtnText = currentBtnText;         
  }, function(error){
        ...
   $scope.openMessageModal($scope.messageModalVariables);  
    $scope.upgradeBtndisabled = false;  
    $scope.upgradeBtnText = currentBtnText;   
  })  
};
```

How do I change the button text when the radio buttons are toggled?
Why does by button text not change when the `save` function is fired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="outputType" value="Database">
    <label>Database</label>
</div>
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="outputType" value="File">
    <label>Xml File</label>
</div>   
<div>
    <button id="upgradeDBButton" type="button" ng-click="UpgradeDatabase()" 
    ng-disabled="upgradeBtndisabled" class="btn btn-info" 
    style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;">{{ upgradeBtndisabled ? 'Processing' : ((outputType == 'Database') ? 'Upgrade' : 'File') }}
   </button>
</div>
```

Will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create $watch, something like

```
$scope.$watch('outputType', function(newVal){
   $scope.upgradeBtnText = newVal === 'Database' ? 'Upgrade' : 'Save';
}
```

Comment: The text button is not changing.  The function is triggered but the text is not changing.